# python create empty object of arbitrary type?

Tags: python, abaqus

for types such as list I can readily create an empty list to make this construct work:

```
 s = []
 s+= [1,2,3]  # result s assigned [1,2,3]
```

obviously useful in constructs like this:

```
 s=[]
 for v in (list1,list2,list3..):
   if condition : s+=v
```

Now I'm working with a user defined type, defined in a module that *I cannot read or change*.. I have to do this:

```
 s=0
 for v in (typefoo1,typefoo2,..):
   if condition :
    if s==0 :
     s=v
    else:
     s+=v
```

This works, but is ugly and occurs so often it is pretty annoying.
so.. is there a way to create an empty object such that the `+=` operator would behave simply like a regular assignment`=` regardless of the type on the r.h.s?

Edit:
I tried to keep the question generic deliberately, but for completeness the type in question is an Abaqus geometry sequence.

Comment: Is `iter` the user defined type, or is `v`?

Comment: sorry a little terse, see edits.  Initializing `s` to `0` or `None` , etc produces a 'unsupported operand type error on += ' error.

Comment: So, just to make this clear: `iter` is an iterable of objects _other than the usual numbers_ that support addition among themselves?

Comment: Exactly, `sum` does not work on this type, although one workaround is to write my own `sum` function specific to this type (Which is somewhat more elegant than the above )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to create an empty object such that the `+=` operator would behave simply like a regular assignment `=` regardless of the type on the r.h.s?

Sure. Just write a class and define your `__add__` method to return the RHS unmodified.

```
class DummyItem:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return other

s = DummyItem()
s += 23
print s
```

Result:

```
23
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list has at least one element, you could just create an iterator and use `next` to get the first element and them sum the rest:

```
i = iter(lst)
s = next(i)
for x in i:
    s += x
```

You could also do this using the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function, with a second paramter specifying the initial value: `s = sum(i, next(i))`. This explicitly *does not work for strings*, but you could also use `reduce` in a similar way, which *will* work with strings: `s = reduce(operator.add, i, next(i))`. Or, you could even combine this with the `DummyItem` from [@Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783541/1639625), as `s = sum(lst, DummyItem())`. This way it also works with strings, and you can use the list directly and do not need to create an iterator.

Comment: the explicit loop works.. unfortunately `sum` throws an "illegal argument type" error..

Comment: @agentp Seems like `sum` explicitly does not work with strings. Could this have been the problem?

Comment: not a string either, but its the same issue - I added specifics of the type to the question.